# Insert Statement in Sql Server with Functions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a scenario where I have created a function which is returning a table variable. I want to use this table variable inside a insert statement. Below is the query

```
INSERT INTO DNVPCDCS..d_CMRequest      
    (PRIORITY, RETRIES,ACTIONCD,FILENAME,TAXONOMY,NOTES,GUID,TOKEN,STATUS,ISDBUSER)       
    VALUES      
    @PRIORITY,0,'INS',@FILENAME,[dbo].[udf_GetTaxonomy](@IMAGEID,@HISTORYNO,@NEW_GUID),@NOTES,@NEW_GUID,@TOKEN,'N',NULL
```

I am not sure about the syntax and am getting error on this.

Comment: That is so wrong I can't even see what you try to do.

Comment: One error is that there are no parenthesis around your Values

Comment: Why would you try to insert a table valued function call into a table cell? What does your function return?

Comment: The function is returning a table from which I need to select values and insert into another table.

Answer (score 2):

You can use INSERT...SELECT syntax like this:

```
INSERT INTO DNVPCDCS..d_CMRequest(PRIORITY, RETRIES,ACTIONCD,FILENAME,TAXONOMY,NOTES,GUID,TOKEN,STATUS,ISDBUSER)
SELECT @PRIORITY,0,'INS',@FILENAME, ... 
    FROM [dbo].[udf_GetTaxonomy](@IMAGEID,@HISTORYNO,@NEW_GUID) t
```

"..." replaces column lists because I have no idea what columns returned by udf_GetTaxonomy.

See [INSERT (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Replace VALUES with SELECT and the same will work. Your code will be:

```
INSERT INTO DNVPCDCS..d_CMRequest     
(PRIORITY, RETRIES, ACTIONCD, FILENAME, TAXONOMY, NOTES, [GUID], TOKEN, [STATUS], ISDBUSER)       
SELECT      
@PRIORITY, 0, 'INS', @FILENAME, [dbo].[udf_GetTaxonomy](@IMAGEID, @HISTORYNO, @NEW_GUID), @NOTES, @NEW_GUID, @TOKEN, 'N', NULL
```